# Connect to a home VPN with a restricted proxy-server in between (macOS)

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, proxy

The network in my university is restricted by a http proxy-server (with authentification). The problem is, that most of my applications are not usable as long as I'm in that network, because they not going through the proxy, like the native email client, CLI-apps, ping, SSH, git or my VPN-server (IpSec) at home.

The HTTP/HTTPS-proxy is on port `8888`

There is also a socks5-proxy with the following allowed ports:

```
Passive (S)FTP TCP/21
SSH TCP/22
Telnet TCP/23
HTTP TCP/80
POP2 TCP/109
POP TCP/110
NNTP TCP/119
IMAP4 TCP/143
IMAP3 TCP/220
HTTPS TCP/443
IMAPS TCP/993
POP3S TCP/995
MMS TCP/1755
RDP TCP/3389
SVN TCP/3690
XMPP/SSL TCP/5223
RA/RV TCP/7070
```

How can I reach **AND** connect to my VPN (IpSec) at home? What are steps? I'm on macOS.

Comment: Can you ssh through the proxy? e.g. `ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc --proxy xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888 %h %p' user@home.host`.

Comment: You can't tunnel IPSec over proxy, so you can use ssh as an alternative vpn with ssh tunnelling.  What services do you want to access over the ipsec vpn?

Answer (score 0):

IPSec is hard to get through proxies. It's much easier to get ssh through. Once you've done that you can start routing traffic over it.

Your first step should be to get an ssh connection running. You have a VPN server running on your home network so I'm going to assume that you can serve ssh too.

The list of open ports you supplied includes ssh, so you should be able to ssh home through the proxy.

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc --proxy xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888 %h %p' user@home.host
```

There's a possibility that the proxy will block ssh connections to your home IP address (i.e. ssh is allowed but connection to your IP isn't). If this is the case you can serve ssh on port 443 to work around it (assuming that https to your home network isn't blocked too).

After you've got ssh working you can forward traffic from your local machine through the ssh connection. You can use ssh to forward traffic on a port by port basis (the `-L` option), or forward everything over the connection with a utility like [sshuttle](http://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html).